# Discrete Derivative in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I've got sensor data in a table in the form:

```
Time      Value
10        100
20        200
36        330
46        440
```

I'd like to pull the change in values for each time period.  Ideally, I'd like to get:

```
Starttime Endtime   Change
10        20        100
20        36        130
36        46        110
```

My SQL skills are pretty rudimentary, so my inclination is to pull all the data out to a script that processes it and then push it back to the new table, but I thought I'd ask if there was a slick way to do this all in the database.

Comment: Would make for an excellent interview question: Trivial to formulate but non-trivial to fix.

Comment: +1 for the fact that you are smart enough to not just do it the way that you already know and asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select a.Time as StartTime
     , b.time as EndTime
     , b.time-a.time as TimeChange
     , b.value-a.value as ValueChange
FROM YourTable a 
Left outer Join YourTable b ON b.time>a.time
Left outer Join YourTable c ON c.time<b.time AND c.time > a.time
Where c.time is null
Order By a.time
```

Comment: This seems a little inefficient to me. Does it make sense to do 2 joins when one join would be enough?  See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299950/sql-difference-between-rows

Answer (score 5):

you could use a SQL window function, below is an example based on BIGQUERY syntax.

```
SELECT 
  LAG(time, 1) OVER (BY time) AS start_time,
  time AS end_time, 
  (value - LAG(value, 1) OVER (BY time))/value AS Change
from data
```

Comment: `OVER (ORDER BY time)` for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select a.Time as StartTime, b.time as EndTime, b.time-a.time as TimeChange, b.value-a.value as ValueChange
FROM YourTable a, YourTable b
WHERE b.time = (Select MIN(c.time) FROM YourTable c WHERE c.time>a.time)
```

Comment: Tested this on my copy of the table and it also works. I like the addition of the time change as well as value change :)

Comment: Also see my other answer, it avoids the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would add an id column to the table so that you have something that predictably increases from row to row.

Then, I would try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.Time AS 'Starttime', t2.Time AS 'Endtime',
    (t2.Value - t1.Value) AS 'Change'
FROM SensorData t1
INNER JOIN SensorData t2 ON (t2.id - 1) = t1.id
ORDER BY t1.Time ASC
```

I'm going to create a test table to try this for myself so I don't know if it works yet but it's worth a shot!

**Update**
Fixed with one minor issue (CHANGE is a protected word and had to be quoted) but tested it and it works! It produces exactly the results defined above.

Comment: This will only work if rows are inserted in order(by startTime), AND no row will ever be deleted; deleting one row will result in a gap so t2.id - t1.id will be > 1

Comment: Indeed, you're right, but given the nature of the data (i.e. coming from a sensor) I would expect the rows to be correctly sequential and a deleted row would be unlikely (I guess) since it would effectively be a gap in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT [Time]
    ,  Value
    ,  RN1 =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time])
    ,  RN2 =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time]) - 1   
FROM  SensorData
)
SELECT  
   StartTime = ISNULL(t1.[time], t2.[time])
 , EndTime = ISNULL(t2.[time], 0)
 , Change = t2.value - t1.value

FROM    T t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        T t2

ON t1.RN1 = t2.RN2
```

Comment: Would work for SQL Server, but I now realise that is not tagged.