# SQL difference between rows

Tags: sql, database

I have a SQL 2008 database table like this

```
name      score
-----------------------
steve     207
steve     205
steve     200
steve     139
```

I want to get the difference between the rows. eqn = [row - (row + 1)]
so I would ideally want it to be,

```
steve 2   //207 - 205
steve 5   //205 - 200
steve 61  //200 - 139
steve 139 //139 - 0
```

What is the best way to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: neat question, any more columns in them there tables?

Comment: Do you have a column that defines the order of the rows? (e.g. sequence_number or score_id)

Comment: I sort the rows by a date column(not included). It's a cumulative score, so date and score will order the same.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```
with cte as
(SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table.name ORDER BY id) row,
   name,
   score
 FROM table)
SELECT 
   a.name ,
   a.score - ISNULL(b.score,0)
FROM
   cte a
   LEFT  JOIN cte b
   on a.name = b.name
    and a.row = b.row+1
```

Comment: Why do you say PARTITION BY is not needed? You are not presuming all the names to be `steve`, are you?

Comment: @Andriy M. Not sure what I was thinking, `a.row = b.row+1`  definitively needs it. Removed the note. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help! There needs to be a comma after row on line 3 for other people looking to this for help.

Comment: @cwhelms glad to help. Thanks for pointing out the missing comma. I fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do it is using lag():

```
SELECT
   name,
   score - coalesce(lag(score) over (partition by name order by id), 0)
FROM table
ORDER BY name, id
```

The lag() function [doesn't seem to be available](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254388/over-clause-enhancement-request-lag-and-lead-functions) in TSQL but this workaround is suggested in the comments:

```
select name,
    score - coalesce(
    MIN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id
             ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    , 0) as diff
from table
order by name, id
```

Comment: +1 But regrettably AFAIK this only works in oracle. The OP's is using SQL 2008 (not tagged but on the first line of his question)

Comment: I think Itzik Ben-Gan was referring to another way to implement it in Oracle. The OVER clause doesn't support ORDER BY for aggregates and SQL doesn't have anything like PRECEDING see this feature request [OVER clause enhancement request - ORDER BY for aggregates](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254387/over-clause-enhancement-request-order-by-for-aggregates)

Comment: No order by for aggregates? Yikes! I couldn't live without those. :-P Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Dennis and Thank you for pointing out how to do it in oracle. I spend time in both Oracle and SQL server and now I've got a new toy to place with :)

Comment: Btw, in Postgres, the coalesce isn't needed if you call: `lag(score, 1, 0)`, 1 and 0 meaning one row and default 0. I suppose the same holds for Oracle; I just wasn't sure. ;-)

Comment: LAG() is available in SQL Server 2012

Comment: It seems that this workaround is more efficient than the one with LEFT JOIN