# SQL Calculation between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following two columns.

```
    Date     |  Market Value
------------------------------
 2016-09-08  |      100
 2016-09-07  |      130
 2016-09-06  |      140
 2016-09-05  |      180
```

I want to add a column that calulcate the difference in `Market Value` between the two dates.

```
    Date     |  Market Value   |  Delta 
------------------------------------------ 
 2016-09-08  |     100         | -30
 2016-09-07  |     130         | -10
 2016-09-06  |     140         | -40
 2016-09-05  |     180         |
```

.

```
100 (2016-09-08) minus 130 (2016-09-07) = -30
```

How do I write that function?

Comment: are you using sql server? When yes which one? SQl Server 2008 or 2012, etc?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012..

Comment: try using the LEAD function and order by date to find the market value of the next month, then just subtract.

Comment: A nice [article on `LEAD` vs `LAG`](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html)  in this case you really don't need to write a function juse use the existing ones...

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012+ the most efficient and simple way is to use the built-in [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213125.aspx) function.

```
SELECT
    [Date]
    ,[Market Value]
    ,LEAD([Market Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) - [Market Value] AS Delta
FROM YourTable
;
```

`LEAD` returns the value of the next row as specified by its `ORDER BY` clause.

All other methods that self-join the table are less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server below 2012 you could try this:

```
with cte as
(SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) row,
   [Date],
   [Market Value]
 FROM [YourTable])
SELECT 
   a.[Date] ,
   b.[Market Value] - ISNULL(a.[Market Value],0) AS Delta
FROM
   cte a
   LEFT  JOIN cte b
   on a.row = b.row+1
```

The original post is from here: [SQL difference between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299950/sql-difference-between-rows)
For SQL-Server 2012 and above you can use the recommended LEAD-Function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have continous date you can do

```
select t1.date, t1.market_value, t1.market_value-t2.market_value from data_table t1 left join data_table t2 on t1.date-1=t2.date
```

If you dont have continous date and want to calculate diffrence between monday and friday you can use rownum for example like this

```
select t1.date, t1.market_value, t1.market_value-t2.market_value from (select rownum, date,market_value from data_table) t1 left join (select rownum, date,market_value from data_table) t2 on t1.rownum-1=t2.rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_DELTA 
@START_DATE DATETIME, 
@END_DATE DATETIME
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE T
    SET DELTA = MARKET_VALUE - (SELECT MARKET_VALUE 
                                FROM YOURTABLE 
                                WHERE [DATE] = T.[DATE] - 1)
    FROM YOURTABLE T
    WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE

END
```

And then to execute:

```
EXEC UPDATE_DELTA '2016-09-05', '2016-09-08'
```

This works as long as you have sequenced dates.

Comment: It's not a really good idea to store calculated values (from other columns.) Data inconsistency you know, when someone updates/deletes/inserts a value.

Answer (score 0):

Add column and update in the following way:

```
UPDATE t SET t.Delta = t.Market_Value-t2.Market_Value
FROM yourtable t
INNER JOIN yourtable t2 ON DATEADD(DD,-1,t.Date) = t2.Date
```

Comment: It's not a really good idea to store calculated values (from other columns.) Data inconsistency you know, when someone updates/deletes/inserts a value.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I agree but this is only for the solution of above requirement but I must mention that in my query sorry for that.