# How to calculate difference of values in a successive rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate difference of two values in successive rows.
Eg: calculate the difference of fuel price with previous day.How to solve this problem using SQL query(values are given below) .please help me

```
Date        Speed      Petrol      Diesel
2018-04-01  79.22       76.41       68.89   
2018-04-02  79.32       76.52       69.01   
2018-04-04  79.45       76.64       69.15   
2018-04-05  79.48       76.67       69.18   
2018-04-06  79.48       76.67       69.21   
2018-04-07  79.5        76.69       69.25   
2018-04-08  79.53       76.72       69.3    
2018-04-09  79.49       76.69       69.27   
2018-04-10  79.48       76.67       69.3    
2018-04-11  79.48       76.67       69.3    
2018-04-12  79.44       76.63       69.27   
2018-04-13  79.4        76.6        69.3
```

Comment: Why are there two Difference columns in your table?

Comment: the easer way is,after receive the data: Date,Speed, calculate the Diference in Angular

Comment: That could be done at once in the database layer @Eliseo. Doing it in the application layer will use up more RAM space, aim for performance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299950/sql-difference-between-rows

Comment: 4 columns none of which look like price to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't on a version which supports windowing functions you could use subqueries to get yesterdays price

```
select `date`,speed,
          speed - ifnull((select speed from t t1 where t1.date < t.date order by t1.date desc limit 1),speed) yesterdayspeed,
          petrol,
          petrol - ifnull((select petrol from t t1 where t1.date < t.date order by t1.date desc limit 1),petrol) yesterdayspetrol,
          diesel,
          diesel - ifnull((select diesel from t t1 where t1.date < t.date order by t1.date desc limit 1),diesel) yesterdaysdiesel
from t;

+------------+-------+----------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+
| date       | speed | yesterdayspeed | petrol | yesterdayspetrol | diesel | yesterdaysdiesel |
+------------+-------+----------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+
| 2018-04-01 | 79.22 |           0.00 |  76.41 |             0.00 |  68.89 |             0.00 |
| 2018-04-02 | 79.32 |           0.10 |  76.52 |             0.11 |  69.01 |             0.12 |
| 2018-04-04 | 79.45 |           0.13 |  76.64 |             0.12 |  69.15 |             0.14 |
| 2018-04-05 | 79.48 |           0.03 |  76.67 |             0.03 |  69.18 |             0.03 |
| 2018-04-06 | 79.48 |           0.00 |  76.67 |             0.00 |  69.21 |             0.03 |
| 2018-04-07 | 79.50 |           0.02 |  76.69 |             0.02 |  69.25 |             0.04 |
| 2018-04-08 | 79.53 |           0.03 |  76.72 |             0.03 |  69.30 |             0.05 |
| 2018-04-09 | 79.49 |          -0.04 |  76.69 |            -0.03 |  69.27 |            -0.03 |
| 2018-04-10 | 79.48 |          -0.01 |  76.67 |            -0.02 |  69.30 |             0.03 |
| 2018-04-11 | 79.48 |           0.00 |  76.67 |             0.00 |  69.30 |             0.00 |
| 2018-04-12 | 79.44 |          -0.04 |  76.63 |            -0.04 |  69.27 |            -0.03 |
| 2018-04-13 | 79.40 |          -0.04 |  76.60 |            -0.03 |  69.30 |             0.03 |
+------------+-------+----------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good opportunity to use the new windowing functions in MySQL 8.0

Assuming one of them relates to fuel price, you want the results in ascending order by date, and a table that looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE tspeed (
  `id` INT auto_increment primary key,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Speed` DECIMAL(5,2),
  `Petrol` DECIMAL(5,2),
  `Diesel` DECIMAL(5,2)
);
```

You could use the LAG() function to get the difference on any of the columns.

e.g.

```
SELECT `id`, `Date`, `Speed`,
  LAG(`Speed`) OVER w AS 'Prev Speed',
  `Speed` - LAG(`Speed`) OVER w AS 'Diff Speed',
  `Petrol`,
  LAG(`Petrol`) OVER w AS 'Prev Petrol',
  `Petrol` - LAG(`Petrol`) OVER w AS 'Diff Petrol',
  `Diesel`,
  LAG(`Diesel`) OVER w AS 'Prev Diesel',
   `Diesel` - LAG(`Diesel`) OVER w AS 'Diff Diesel'
FROM tspeed
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY `Date` ASC);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nLTRhsUKELy6YpMSAEKrCN/5

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to me some business logic. It would be better to do this in you code rather than in sql query i believe.

You can fetch all the data in the list of you row object and can find difference.

Comment: This should be a comment @ishantg

Comment: Not allowed to comment since reputation is less than 50 :)