# How to calculate difference between rows with SQL?

Tags: sql, difference

I have a task to create a table with the one new column with the difference between ages in current and next row. The ages should be in descending order. Is it possible to do with SQL?
I don't know exactly what sql I should use and that wasn't specified in task.

I understand that there should be something in brackets

```
SELECT name, age, (...) AS difference
FROM Animals
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

The table "Animals" I have

```
id  |  name  | age
 1  | Molly  |  4
 2  | Jackson|  8 
 3  | Wonka  |  38
 4  | Polly  |  7
```

The result table should look like this:

```
  name  | age | difference
 Wonka  | 38  |  30
 Jackson|  8  |  1
 Polly  |  7  |  3
 Molly  |  4  |
```

Comment: ANSI/ISO standard SQL where the sql tag is about on this website has `LAG()` and `LEAD()` to make it possible to read a previous and next record..But because you mentioned brackets i assume you are using SQL Server (MSSQL) as RDMS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL difference between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299950/sql-difference-between-rows)

Comment: One question what should happen when there are "ties" in the ages.

Answer (score 5):

You need `lead()` function:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  age, 
  age - lead(age) over (order by age desc, name) AS difference
FROM Animals
ORDER BY age DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e4f0447212e511f6af7f02856512103).
Results:

```
> name    | age | difference
> :------ | --: | ---------:
> Wonka   |  38 |         30
> Jackson |   8 |          1
> Polly   |   7 |          3
> Molly   |   4 |
```

Comment: @Lisa `age - lead(age) over (order by age desc, name <ASC|DESC>) AS difference` might even be "required" to handle "ties" better.as `lead(age) over (order by age desc)` will return randomly when the age ties.. But not sure how important this is for the topicstarter

Answer (score 2):

You would use `lag()`/`lead()` and `order by`:

```
select a.*,
       (a - lag(age) over (order by age)) as diff
from animals a
order by age desc;
```

The `order by` in the `lag()` does not need to match the `order by` in the outer query.  The first defines "previous row".  The second is for the presentation of the data.

Comment: @Lisa `age - lead(age) over (order by age desc, name <ASC|DESC>) AS difference` might even be "required" to handle "ties" better.as `lead(age) over (order by age desc)` will return randomly when the age ties.. But not sure how important this is for the topicstarter

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using the MAX function, which operates on the corresponding [window of rows](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_window_function).

```
with Animals as (
  select 1 as id, 'Molly' as name, 4 as age union all
  select 2, 'Jackson', 8 union all
  select 3, 'Wonka', 38 union all
  select 4, 'Polly', 7
)
select
  name, age,
  age - max(age) over(
          order by age
          rows between unbounded preceding
          and 1 preceding
        )
from Animals
order by age desc;
```

**Output:**

```
+---------+-----+------------+
|  name   | age | difference |
+---------+-----+------------+
| Wonka   |  38 | 30         |
| Jackson |   8 | 1          |
| Polly   |   7 | 3          |
| Molly   |   4 | NULL       |
+---------+-----+------------+
```