# SQL - Setting values with looped execution

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mongodb

I want to test some stock trading strategies and I'm trying to figure out how easily I can create calculated fields with SQL (mySQL) rather than MongoDB with Python like I was doing previously.

I have 5 years of data for about 3,000 tickers and I want to be able to experiment and set additional columns as needed.  This can be a pretty slow process with Python/MongoDB and while `pandas` is pretty intuitive in terms of calculating and setting values on a by-ticker basis, I'm thinking I could speed it up if I could accomplish the same things in SQL (and I really need to get better at SQL).  SQL is also less bulky than MongoDB and I might end up with a large number of calculated fields.

Specifically, I would have to do the following:

1. Create an array based on distinct ticker values in the table.
2. Loop through the array and perform executions on a by-ticker basis.
3. Each loop would require having to select only rows related to each ticker and then perform calculations that require referencing multiple rows (e.g., a "Change" field could be calculated by finding the percentage change between two "Close" fields on consecutive rows.

I found something that indicated that I could do #3 here: [SQL difference between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299950/sql-difference-between-rows)

I think I would just need to alter that query to only select a certain ticker, but I'm really not sure if I can do #1 and #2.  I see that I can create an array but I'm not sure how to do that dynamically for the unique values in the database.  For #2, I see that it's possible to create a `while` loop but not a `for` loop (although there are probably ways to use a `while` loop as a `for` loop).

I think if I get #1, I can get the rest, but any suggestions are appreciated.  Also any general feedback about whether it even makes sense to do this in SQL.

Comment: You can probably do what you want in SQL, but not the way you describe it. To start, MySQL has no native "array" data type. It simply isn't part of the language. I would suggest that you ask a *new* question. Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of one or two or three representative calculations you want in mind. That would provide examples of how you would express the logic in SQL.

Comment: I suppose I could get a count of the distinct tickers, find the nth ticker corresponding with the loop iteration, and perform the calculations accordingly.  Any idea how this would compare to Python in terms of speed?

Comment: For one python is one of the slowest language so unless you are doing something remarkably ineffecient it will always be faster than python....

Comment: I used a string with comma-separated values in place of a true array and it works that way.  I still need to add row iteration calculations mentioned in #3 above to test the speed aspect.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic example where the field `Test` is set based on the index of the ticker within the distinct ticker values.  The trick was to mimic an array using comma-separated values within a string and then iterate through the string.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS set_fields;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE set_fields()
    BEGIN
        /* Get ticker count (for WHILE loop max iterations) and comma-separated tickers */
        SET @tickerCount = (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Ticker) FROM price_history
        );
        SET @tickers = (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Ticker) FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT v.Ticker
                FROM price_history AS v
            ) as Tickers
        );
        SET @i = 0;
        
        WHILE @i < @tickerCount DO
            /* Loop through tickers in @tickers and call UPDATE */
        
            SET @comma = POSITION(',' IN @tickers);
            
            IF @comma = 0 THEN
                SET @ticker = @tickers;
            ELSE
                SET @ticker = SUBSTRING(@tickers, 1, @comma-1);
                SET @tickers = SUBSTRING(@tickers, @comma+1);
            END IF; 
            
            UPDATE price_history SET Test = @i WHERE Ticker = @ticker;
            SET @i = @i + 1;

        END WHILE;
        
    END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL set_fields();
```