# Derivative / time difference for time series data in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am querying a dataset of requests and am looking to get "up-time" between service requests. This post [Discrete Derivative in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986889/discrete-derivative-in-sql) is pretty much what I am after. However, I am working with date time data and I don't believe I can assume the work orders will be sorted chronologically. Also, I have specific locations to each request.

| Request | Location | RequestDate | CompleteDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R-001 | a | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 |
| R-002 | a | 3/17/2020 | 3/20/2020 |
| R-004 | b | 2/27/2020 | 3/1/2020 |
| R-003 | b | 4/22/2020 | 4/23/2020 |
| R-005 | a | 7/3/2020 | 7/7/2020 |

I do see the [SQL DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) function.
Below is a slight modification from the top answer in the referenced post.

```
Select a.RequestDate as StartTime
     , b.CompleteDate as EndTime
     , DATEDIFF(b.RequestDate-a.CompleteDate) as TimeChange
FROM YourTable a 
Left outer Join YourTable b ON b.time>a.time
Left outer Join YourTable c ON c.time<b.time AND c.time > a.time
Where c.time is null
Order By a.RequestDate
```

Also, I kind of grasp aliasing the same table twice but not fully. I don't understand the outer join either.
Eventually I'd like the new column...I might be able to make the assumption or order by request date earlier if that simplifies the problem.

| Request | Location | RequestDate | CompleteDate | Up-Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R-001 | a | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | null |
| R-002 | a | 3/17/2020 | 3/20/2020 | 72 |
| R-004 | b | 2/27/2020 | 3/1/2020 | null |
| R-003 | b | 4/22/2020 | 4/23/2020 | 52 |
| R-005 | a | 7/3/2020 | 7/7/2020 | 105 |

I am hoping it isn't too different from the original post, with a group by location and order by request date thrown in there somewhere.

Comment: Can you assume that the CompleteDate for a particular request is before the next (chronologically) RequestDate for that location? IE can a particular location have two tickets active at once?

Comment: where are the time stamps?

Comment: In the post you found, try reading some of the other suggestions, especially the one containing the `LAG` window function.  You might find that useful.  It's a more direct way to use values from a prior row, just as you seem to need, without using a `JOIN`.

Comment: Note also: You will do the sorting based on date/time or other criteria in your data.  If your data doesn't contain enough detail for this ordering, how do you expect to identify rows between which to calculate this up-time difference?  You'll also be able to calculation running sums with window functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the LAG window function to perform a difference (in days) between this RequestDate and the previous CompleteDate for each Location separately, ordered by the RequestDate (some assumptions here).

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    Request      VARCHAR(30)
  , Location     VARCHAR(10)
  , RequestDate  date
  , CompleteDate date
);

INSERT INTO log VALUES 
  ('R-001', 'a',  '2020-1-1',    '2020-1-5' )
, ('R-002', 'a',  '2020-3-17',   '2020-3-20')
, ('R-004', 'b',  '2020-2-27',   '2020-3-1' )
, ('R-003', 'b',  '2020-4-22',   '2020-4-23')
, ('R-005', 'a',  '2020-7-3',    '2020-7-7' )
;
```

The query:

```
SELECT log.*
     , LAG(CompleteDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY RequestDate) AS prev_date
     , RequestDate - LAG(CompleteDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY RequestDate) AS diff
  FROM log
 ORDER BY Location, RequestDate 
;
```

Result:

[image: Result of Test]

[Working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=87c0adf7774ab35336d52f6b6ed4188d)

Additional SQL to address the string to date conversion issue (PostgreSQL):

```
WITH logs AS (
        SELECT Request, Location
             , TO_DATE(RequestDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')  AS RequestDate
             , TO_DATE(CompleteDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CompleteDate
          FROM log
     )
SELECT log.*
     , LAG(CompleteDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY RequestDate) AS prev_date
     , RequestDate - LAG(CompleteDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY RequestDate) AS diff
  FROM logs AS log
 ORDER BY Location, RequestDate 
;
```

[The updated working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b867bdce69d2361df0c68fc4fa58db1f)

Comment: Thanks, as @alexherm notes, how would I convert this to work with my current string format. I would think I could just wrap them with a:
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), log.RequestDate, 101) FROM log;

Comment: @AKA_Tom Sure.  You could even do that in a prior CTE term (`WITH` clause) and keep the above expression that operates on date types. It's sometimes best to just separate the questions. How to convert string to date is one question.  How to handle the derivative logic is another.  Note: Your initial question doesn't provide much SQL detail, like the exact table and column types, plus insert statements to provide data.  See my test case as a good example to follow and the kind of detail a question should contain.

Comment: @AKA_Tom I added an extra query to address the conversion.  It's not necessary to do it like this.  But it's clear and easy to understand.